# my phone 640xl automatically activated double tap option

Tags: lumia-640-xl, screen

I am using a Microsoft Lumia 640XL, and double tap option automatically activated for all option with sound.
i.e. for open screen say double tap; call say double tap

please help for unlocking the same.

Comment: I appreciate that English might not be your first language, but it's difficult to determine what you' like help with here - are you wanting to use the "double tap to wake" feature available on some devices, or are you wanting to have a double tap gesture globally recognised to do something you configure, such as launching the phone dialler?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are talking about the Narrator option which reads all the text on the screen and perform actions on double-taps. Assuming that, solution to your problem is Go to settings > double tap ease of access > double tap narrator > double tap the On button to turn it off. Now the narrator is off.  To unlock your phone while narrator is on you have to double tap every number of your pin since single tap will only read that number aloud and will not allow you to enter the number. Hopefully I understood your problem well and hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To deactivate the narrator you have to hold both the volume buttons and click the Windows icon on your screen and it will stop.

Comment: Could you clarify the "click the Windows icon on your screen" part? Do you mean tapping the Windows button?